# How to make a call from linux with android phone?

Tags: android, linux, sms

I need to make a phone call and\or send SMS from my debian server.android phone is plugged to the server by USB cable.
I can connect to the phone from the server  via: USB, Bluetooth or WIFI(ssh).

Are there any possibility to make any GSM call in "UNIX way", without writing custom applications to android? 
Something like:

```
root@android:~# sendsms 01806717178 "Hello, kitty!"
```

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. You have to show an effort. No one here is going to code the amount of work it would take to create something like that.

Comment: Connor Tumbleson, I do not ask to do it totaly for me. I ask to show me the way how my task can be done. I ask to show me are there any tools for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
service call phone 2 s16 "+18001231234"
```

See [how-to-call-from-console](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9963/how-to-call-from-console)

(5 seconds google search with `android phone call cli` patterns)

Comment: D'oh... I'm stupid one :( Thank you a lot!

Comment: I don't think so, searching google can be learnt =)